# Change Visual Studio project's applicationhost.config where to do these

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, applicationhost

I want to do these:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 en.localhost
127.0.0.1 api.localhost
127.0.0.1 en.api.localhost
```

where in the project's `config\applicationhost.config` file - how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have windows pc, you can add this lines to the Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file. It will redirect hostaddress to the matching ip.
After that, don’t forget to run “ipconfig/flushdns” in command line.